# how would I pass pointer to a queue as an argument in pthread_create (getting incompatible conversion warning)?

Tags: c, multithreading

I cannot figure out how correctly pass my queue pointer to a pthread_create function.

Here is snippet of my code:

```
queue_t *queue_arr[number_of_categories];
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < number_of_categories; i++){
    queue_arr[i] = queue_create();
}
```

trying to create thread with a pointer to a queue in a loop:
//loop and some code here

```
if (pthread_create(&tid[i+1], NULL, consumer_thread, (void *)queue_arr[i]) != 0 ){
    perror("pthread_create for consumer failed");
    exit(-1);
};
```

it gives me a warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types passing 'void *(queue_t)' to parameter of type 'void *(*)(void *)'
```

Not sure how would I change queue_arr[i] in a correct manner for pthread_create.

Thanks for help guys

Comment: Read the warning message again, it's not the `(void *)queue_arr[i]` expression that the warning is about. Hint: Check the `consumer_thread` function prototype/definition and see if you can find anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function prototype/definition for `consumer_thread` should be like 
`void* consumer_thread(void* arg)` and pthread_create statement as `pthread_create(&tid[i+1], NULL, consumer_thread, (void *)queue_arr[i])`. Finally in your `consumer_thread` function you can typecast your `arg` back to `queue_t*` datatype.